# Postgres Doesn't Return Results for a Value in the Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following problem where a value returned from a table doesn't return anything when queried with that value:

```
select * from my_table limit 2;
  id  |         zone         |     geo     
--------+----------------------+---------------
 9yjyyf |  America/Chicago     |  051059528002
 9yrw3j |  America/Chicago     |  050219503002
```

Then, when I do a select count or a select on the table I get an empty set as the result:

```
select count(*) from my_table where geo = '051059528002';

 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

This is the table definition:

```
 \d my_table 
      Table "public.my_table"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------+------------------------+-----------
 id   | character varying(12)  | 
 zone   | character varying(100) | 
 geo  | character varying(32)  | 
Indexes:
    "geo_idx" btree (geoid)
    "id_idx" btree (tile)
```

Comment: the column might have leading or trailing spaces? check for the trimmed value if that is the case

Comment: I agree with vamsi, try `where trim(geo) = '051059528002'`. Also: what is your exact Postgres version (use `select version()` to get that)

Comment: Thank you, trim happened to be the solution

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala please, add your comment as an answer, so c00der can mark it as accepted

Comment: Yes, I can accept if the comment is posted as a answer